# Is there a way to detect the FAILED kafka connect task

Tags: apache-kafka, prometheus, jmx-exporter

The JMX Exporter is able to export Prometheus metrics (kafka_connect_task_status) regarding Kafka Connect. JMX Exporter is able to expose any running/paused connector tasks. 
However, it doesn't display any failed tasks, and once a running task fails, the task will no longer be exposed by the JMX Exporter. 
How do I capture the failed task? 
Has anyone here encountered the same issue and managed to get the resolution on that?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/prometheus-users/KZQT-nYw3AM/v-dGm80kBAAJ). Add this pattern to kafka-connect. It pivots the string value of the status to a label and adds a constant value of 1.

```
      - pattern: 'kafka.connect<type=connector-task-metrics, connector=(.+), task=(.+)><>status: (.+)'
    name: kafka_connect_task_status
    value: 1
    labels:
      connector: "$1"
      task: "$2"
      status: "$3"
```